# Around Plugins ( Interceptors) in magento can be used to suppress before and after plugin execution?

Tags: magento2, after-plugin, around-plugin, before-plugin

In around plugin function, if we don't use proceed() then after plugin execution will be suppressed. Is there anyway by which we can suppress before plugin execution?

Answer (score 1):

Why not wrap everything inside `around` plugin for your case? So that:

```
public function aroundFunction(\My\Module\Model\MyUtility $subject, callable $proceed){
    //If condition is true
    if (true){
        //BeforeFunction
        //Do sonething
        //ExecuteFunction
        $proceed();
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree with your solution to add condition to prevent after plugin.
Is there anyway by which we can supress **before** part of around plugin.

Comment: No, this is the only way. Once you entered `Function` you cannot avoid "before".